# Rails database boolean values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, boolean

Code first:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  ...
  t.boolean :is_active, :default => true
  ...
end
```

Now, here is my issue - I am creating a rake task to import a LARGE number of records (10,000+). I've done extensive testing and benchmarking and determined that the fastest and most efficient way to perform this task is to create one giant raw SQL statement. (I'm reading data from CSV). As an example:

```
inserts = Array.new
FasterCSV.foreach(...) do |row|
  inserts.push "(row[0], row[1]...)"
end
User.connection.execute "INSERT INTO users (...) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
```

Everything works great. The entire process completes in (literally) seconds instead of the 1.5 hours using ActiveRecord. However, my problem lies with the boolean field. I develop locally on SQLite, but MySQL on production. When using ActiveRecord, Rails determines what to put in the "boolean" field (since almost all databases are different). I'm writing custom SQL and I want to know if there is a way I can do something like...

```
INSERT INTO users(..., is_active, ...) VALUES (..., ActiveRecord::Base.connection.boolean.true, ...)
```

...that correctly returns the database-specific boolean value.

Anyone who answers "just using ActiveRecord" will be down-voted. It's simply NOT feasible in this situation. I'm also not willing to use a tinyint(1) field and use 1's or 0's.

In summary, the value for `is_active` needs to change based on the current database connection...

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why don't you develop locally with MySQL? That would solve this problem, along with other incompatibilities. They way I usually deal with booleans is to use a prepared statement, but won't work for you.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question though. What if I want to use POSTgres or MSSQL at some point?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe that you might be looking for `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quoted_true`

This returns native boolean values in quotes, e.g. '1' for SQL Server or MySQL, and 't' for PostgreSQL or SQLite

Comment: Thank you so much! How/where did you find this?! Also, it may be worth editing your answer (just for other people who may have this problem) to mention that it automatically includes the quotes ('). For example, if the connection is sqlite, it returns 't' not just t.

Comment: Heh, to find it, I had some fun looking through the codes for ActiveRecord connection adapters.

Comment: Just for clarity: You can use self.connection.quoted_* in class methods and self.class.connection.quoted_* in instance methods.